# Collection List empties itself

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, collections, visual-studio-2017, npgsql

I have a class for adding parameters to a database (PostgreSQL) connection object that inherits `System.Collections.CollectionBase`. This class is in a common library I use for multiple applications. Usually, it adds the objects without a problem, but I've started encountering a strange issue where the collection empties its objects for no apparent reason. This results in an error with the SQL statement not being built properly.

---

### ENVIRONMENT

- Windows 10 Pro x64 (19042.804)
- Visual Studio 2017 CE (4.8.0484)
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 (Library & Application)
- PostgreSQL Server v12.1
- Npgsql 5.0.3 (*see below*)

---

### TROUBLESHOOTING

Here's the (*obfuscated*) code where the issue is occurring:

```vb
SQLCommand = "INSERT INTO table" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += "(" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column1," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column2," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column3," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column4," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column5," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column6," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column7," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column8," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column9," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & "column10" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += ")" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += "VALUES" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += "(" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter1," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter2," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter3," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter4," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter5," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter6," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter7," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter8," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter9," & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += vbTab & ":parameter10" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += ")" & vbCrLf
SQLCommand += "RETURNING pkid"

PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter1", value1) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter2", value2) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter3", value3) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter4", value4) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter5", value5) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter6", value6) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter7", value7) 'String - THIS IS WHERE THE LIST CLEARS
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter8", value8) 'Boolean
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter9", value9) 'String
PGDB.Parameters.Add(":parameter10", value10) 'String

MyID = Convert.ToInt32(PGDB.ExecuteStatementScalar(SQLCommand))
```

The `PGDB` object is my `Npgsql` database connection object and the `Parameters` object is the inherited collection. The first six parameters add to the collection without issue, but as soon as it goes to add the seventh, the entire list empties itself and starts over. The executing SQL statement *should* look like this:

```sql
-- EXPECTED SQL - WHAT IS STORED IN THE SQLCommand VARIABLE
INSERT INTO table
(
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5,
    column6,
    column7,
    column8,
    column9,
    column10
)
VALUES
(
    :parameter1,
    :parameter2,
    :parameter3,
    :parameter4,
    :parameter5,
    :parameter6,
    :parameter7,
    :parameter8,
    :parameter9,
    :parameter10
)
RETURNING pkid
```

...but, what I get instead is this:

```sql
-- ACTUAL (WRONG) SQL EXECUTED BY THE DATABASE
INSERT INTO table
(
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5,
    column6,
    column7,
    column8,
    column9,
    column10
)
VALUES
(
    :parameter1,
    :parameter2,
    :parameter3,
    :parameter4,
    :parameter5,
    :parameter6,
    $1,
    $2,
    $3,
    $4
)
RETURNING pkid
```

...which then generates an `Npgsql.PostgresException` complaining about the syntax when it actually tries to execute the SQL statement:

`42601: syntax error at or near ":"`

I've put in breakpoints to step through the process but it's always the same behavior. Here are some screenshots from my IDE:

Here's what the `Parameters` collection object looks like before the first parameter is added:
[image: Before First Parameter Added]

Here it is after the sixth parameter is added:
[image: After Sixth Parameter Added]

And here's what it looks like as soon as it enters execution of the `Add()` method on the seventh parameter:
[image: Adding Seventh Parameter]

To be sure, I also checked the state as it enters execution of the `Add()` method on the sixth parameter:
[image: Adding Sixth Parameter]

This method worked without error at one time, so I'm not sure why it "all of a sudden" stopped working. In my attempt to fix this and get all of the parameters to load correctly, I upgraded the `Npgsql` library from version 4.1.8 to 5.0.3. After I fought with it for a while - *I had to resolve some version conflicts with the `System.Buffers` library* - I was able to get it running again but, unfortunately, I got the exact same results.

Just in case it might be a memory issue, I went ahead and shut down everything and rebooted the computer. That also did not resolve the issue.

For reference, here's a trimmed-down version of the `PGSQLParameters` class, excluding various overloads for different value types.

```vb
Imports Npgsql

#Region "POSTGRESQL PARAMETER COLLECTION OBJECT"
Public Class PGSQLParameters
    Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Enum SQLDecimalType
        SQLMoney = 1
        SQLDecimal = 2
    End Enum

#Region "COLLECTION ADD AND SUPPORT METHODS"
#Region "PUBLIC METHODS FOR ADDING ITEMS TO THE COLLECTION"
    '-- Input Parameter
    Public Overloads Sub Add(ByVal ParameterName As String, ByVal DataType As DbType, ByVal Size As Int32, ByVal Value As Object)
        If ParameterName.Length = 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        If TypeOf (Value) Is String AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Value)) Then
            Value = DBNull.Value
        End If

        If Not ParameterName.StartsWith(":") Then
            ParameterName = ParameterName.Insert(0, ":")
        End If

        List.Add(BuildParameter(ParameterName, DataType, Size, ParameterDirection.Input, Value))
    End Sub

#Region "INPUT OVERLOADS"
    '-- String
    Public Overloads Sub Add(ByVal ParameterName As String, ByVal Value As String)
        Dim StringLength As Integer = 0

        If Not Value = Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) Then
            StringLength = Value.Length
        End If

        Add(ParameterName, DbType.String, StringLength, Value)
    End Sub
#End Region
#End Region

    Private Function BuildParameter(ByVal ParameterName As String, ByVal DataType As DbType, ByVal Size As Int32, ByVal Direction As ParameterDirection, ByVal Value As Object) As NpgsqlParameter
        Dim NewParameter As NpgsqlParameter

        If Size > 0 Then
            NewParameter = New NpgsqlParameter(ParameterName, DataType, Size)
        Else
            NewParameter = New NpgsqlParameter(ParameterName, DataType)
        End If

        NewParameter.Direction = Direction

        If Not (Direction = ParameterDirection.Output AndAlso Value Is Nothing) Then
            NewParameter.Value = DBNull.Value

            If Not Value Is Nothing Then
                NewParameter.Value = Value
            ElseIf TypeOf (Value) Is Boolean Then
                NewParameter.Value = Value
            End If
        End If

        Return NewParameter
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
#End Region
```

I don't see any reason for this spontaneous "clearing" of the `Parameters` collection, especially since all of the parameters leading up to and including the "problem" are `String` values, so they're all using the exact same method call (I've confirmed this in my walk-through). Additionally, based on the executing SQL, it *looks* like it's actually somehow *preserving* the first six parameters in the collection object and just not adding the new ones, which makes absolutely no sense.

Also, it doesn't look like it's completely reinstantiating the object because, as the screenshots show, the `Capacity` doesn't change from the sixth to the seventh parameter. If I had to say anything, it looks like it's cloning the collection after six parameters have been added, then discarding that clone and/or ignoring it completely. Again, it just makes no sense to me.

I wouldn't doubt that I'm simply overlooking something, but I have no idea what that "something" would be. Has anyone else encountered this type of behavior? Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. If I can or need to provide any additional details, let me know.

Comment: I would suggest that you reimplement `PGSQLParameters` to inherit `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of NpgsqlParameter)`. The result will be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @jmcilhinney. I may very well look into this, although I'm not sure how soon I'll be able to get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue, but the cause is something I wouldn't have expected and probably wouldn't be obvious without a *complete* listing of a good deal more code. I apologize for not providing enough detail in the original question, but I hadn't guessed where I'd eventually find the cause of the issue.

As I indicated above, the issue always occurred with the same parameter in the sequence. The value I was attempting to assign to that specific parameter was a Public Property (`String`) of a `Lazy(Of T)` object in another class.

The object in question looks something like this:

```vb
#Region "REAL ESTATE OBJECT"
''' <summary>
''' Standard object containing details about a specific piece of real estate
''' </summary>
Public Class RealEstate
#Region "PRIVATE FIELDS"
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _RealEstateTypeCode As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _PhysicalStreet1 As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _PhysicalStreet2 As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _PhysicalCity As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _PhysicalState As String

    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private _PhysicalZIPCode As String
#End Region

#Region "PRIVATE PROPERTIES"
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private Property PGDB As PGSQLDB

#Region "LAZY PROPERTIES"
    ' >> THIS IS THE PROPERTY THAT APPEARS TO HAVE CAUSED THE ISSUE <<
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> <DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)>
    Private Property _RealEstateType As Lazy(Of PropertyType) =
    New Lazy(Of PropertyType)(Function()
                                    Return New PropertyType(_RealEstateTypeCode, Me.CIADB)
                                End Function)
#End Region
#End Region

#Region "PUBLIC PROPERTIES"
    Public Property RealEstateID As Integer

    Public Property PhysicalStreet1 As String
        Get
            Return _PhysicalStreet1
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                If value.Trim.Length > 120 Then
                    _PhysicalStreet1 = value.Trim.Substring(0, 120).Trim.ToUpper
                Else
                    _PhysicalStreet1 = value.Trim.ToUpper
                End If
            Else
                _PhysicalStreet1 = String.Empty
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhysicalStreet2 As String
        Get
            Return _PhysicalStreet2
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                If value.Trim.Length > 120 Then
                    _PhysicalStreet2 = value.Trim.Substring(0, 120).Trim.ToUpper
                Else
                    _PhysicalStreet2 = value.Trim.ToUpper
                End If
            Else
                _PhysicalStreet2 = String.Empty
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhysicalCity As String
        Get
            Return _PhysicalCity
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                If value.Trim.Length > 60 Then
                    _PhysicalCity = value.Trim.Substring(0, 60).Trim.ToUpper
                Else
                    _PhysicalCity = value.Trim.ToUpper
                End If
            Else
                _PhysicalCity = String.Empty
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhysicalState As String
        Get
            If _PhysicalState Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(_PhysicalState) OrElse _PhysicalState = "XX" Then
                If Not _PhysicalZIPCode Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_PhysicalZIPCode) Then
                    _PhysicalState = Utility.GetStateCodeFromZIP(_PhysicalZIPCode)
                End If
            End If

            Return _PhysicalState
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                If value.Trim.Length > 2 Then
                    _PhysicalState = Utility.GetStateCodeFromName(value.Trim)
                Else
                    If [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(USState), value.Trim.ToUpper) Then
                        Dim PState As USState

                        If [Enum].TryParse(value.Trim.ToUpper, PState) Then
                            _PhysicalState = Utility.GetStateCodeFromName(PState.GetEnumDescription)
                        End If
                    Else
                        _PhysicalState = value.Trim.ToUpper
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                _PhysicalState = "OK"
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhysicalZIPCode As String
        Get
            Return _PhysicalZIPCode
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            If Not value Is Nothing Then
                If value.Trim.Length > 10 Then
                    _PhysicalZIPCode = value.Trim.Substring(0, 10).Trim.ToUpper
                Else
                    _PhysicalZIPCode = value.Trim.ToUpper
                End If
            Else
                _PhysicalZIPCode = String.Empty
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property RealEstateTypeCode As String
        Set(value As String)
            _RealEstateTypeCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property RealEstateType As PropertyType
        Get
            Return _RealEstateType.Value
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region
```

In my original obfuscated code I simply injected a generic string as a placeholder, but it appears that the issue has everything to do with this specific assignment. The other values being added to the parameter list are "regular" properties of the object that are immediately accessible. But, something seems to "short circuit" when calling the `Add()` method using a `Lazy(Of T)` object for the `Value` parameter.

In order to "fix" the issue, I've declared an additional local `String` variable that retrieves the value of the needed property from this `Lazy(Of T)` object. I then use that ***local variable*** for assigning to the `Add()` method's `Value` parameter:

```vb
With REObject 'A RealEstate object
    ' > DECLARING THIS LOCAL VARIABLE TO RETRIEVE THE VALUE OF THE LAZY PROPERTY
    Dim TypeCode As String = .RealEstateType.TypeCode
...
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("street1", .PhysicalStreet1)
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("street2", .PhysicalStreet2)
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("city", .PhysicalCity)
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("state", .PhysicalState)
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("zip", .PhysicalZIPCode)
    ' > CHANGED THE FOLLOWING
    ' PGDB.Parameters.Add("type", .RealEstateType.TypeCode) 'String - THIS IS WHERE THE LIST CLEARS
    ' > TO USE THE LOCAL VARIABLE INSTEAD OF THE LAZY OBJECT'S PROPERTY VALUE
    PGDB.Parameters.Add("type", TypeCode)
    ' > THE VALUE IS NOW SUCCESSFULLY ADDED
...
End With
```

Executing *this* code results in all of the parameters correctly populating with the correct values and the SQL statement executing in the database without error. So, it would seem that the fact that the `Lazy(Of T)` object hasn't been "filled" yet is causing some unexpected (*for me, at least*) behavior when entering the `Add()` method. To be honest, I'm *still* not sure why it was "resetting" the `.List` property of the `Collection` object when attempting to use the `Lazy(Of T)` object's property value, but at least this resolution achieves the desired goal. Again, I apologize for not providing enough detail initially, but hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Might need to post more code - the posted code doesn't seem to exhibit any problem for me:

[image]

Drag this icon to your desktop, rename it as .zip and open it:

[image]

It has the exact solution files I used to check your issue (it doesn't show the issue on my computer)

Comment: That is so strange. As I said, this code *used to* work without a problem, so what you're seeing is what I expect to see. Also, I have several other applications using this code that seem to work just fine with the only difference I've been able to find being that this particular statement has more parameters than I've been able to find in my other systems. I can post the entire PostgreSQL connector object, although it's rather lengthy.

Comment: I added my project that I used to try and repro your issue, see the end of the answer

Comment: Okay. Like in your example, I just declared a new collection object that wasn't tied to anything else and was able to add several items to it without a problem. But, when I ran the code I listed above, it still exhibited the same behavior. However, I believe I found the cause of the issue and it has *something* to do with trying to add a value from a `Lazy` property to the collection.